# kivy Cannot convert float to kivy.properties.Property

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

I'm trying to have a button which can be clicked to add two buttons below the most recently added buttons.  I'm doing this with a float `height` which starts at .9 and decrements from there.  I'm getting the error TypeError: Cannot convert float to kivy.properties.Property.

```
class TasksWindow(FloatLayout):
    height = .9

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(TasksWindow, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        addBtn = Button(
            text="+", pos_hint={'x': .9, 'top': 1}, size_hint=(.1, .1))
        self.add_widget(addBtn)
        addBtn.bind(on_press=self.clkAdd)

    def clkAdd(self, obj):
        height = obj.height
        editBtn = Button(text="Tap to Edit", pos_hint={
            'x': 0.0, 'top': height}, size_hint=(.9, .1))
        delBtn = Button(text="X", pos_hint={
                        'x': .9, 'top': height}, size_hint=(.1, .1))
        height -= .1
        self.add_widget(editBtn)
        self.add_widget(delBtn)


class TasksApp(App):
    def build(self): 
        window = TasksWindow() 
        return window


if __name__ == '__main__':
    TasksApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `kivy.properties.NumericProperty`. Ensure not to override a property name. `FloatLayout` has a height property.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty


class TasksWindow(FloatLayout):
    btn_height = NumericProperty(0.9)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(TasksWindow, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        add_btn = Button(text="+", pos_hint={'x': .9, 'top': 1}, size_hint=(.1, .1))
        self.add_widget(add_btn)
        add_btn.bind(on_press=self.click_add)

    def click_add(self, obj):
        height = self.btn_height
        edit_btn = Button(text="Tap to Edit", pos_hint={
            'x': 0.0, 'top': height}, size_hint=(.9, .1))
        del_btn = Button(text="X", pos_hint={
                        'x': .9, 'top': height}, size_hint=(.1, .1))
        self.btn_height -= .1
        self.add_widget(edit_btn)
        self.add_widget(del_btn)


class TasksApp(App):
    def build(self): 
        return TasksWindow() 


if __name__ == '__main__':
    TasksApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

You are encountering the following error because you are using Kivy keyword, height

> TypeError: Cannot convert float to kivy.properties.Property

Replace:

```
height = .9
```

with:

```
parent_height = NumericProperty(.9)    # 90% height of its parent layout
```

## Example

### main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty


class TasksWindow(FloatLayout):
    parent_height = NumericProperty(.9)    # 90% height of its parent layout

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(TasksWindow, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        addBtn = Button(
            text="+", pos_hint={'x': .9, 'top': 1}, size_hint=(.1, .1))
        self.add_widget(addBtn)
        addBtn.bind(on_press=self.clkAdd)

    def clkAdd(self, obj):
        editBtn = Button(text="Tap to Edit", pos_hint={
            'x': 0.0, 'top': self.parent_height}, size_hint=(.9, .1))
        delBtn = Button(text="X", pos_hint={
                        'x': .9, 'top': self.parent_height}, size_hint=(.1, .1))
        self.parent_height -= .1
        self.add_widget(editBtn)
        self.add_widget(delBtn)


class TasksApp(App):
    def build(self):
        window = TasksWindow()
        return window


if __name__ == '__main__':
    TasksApp().run()
```

### Output

[image: Figure 1 - App Startup]
[image: Figure 2 - Clicked "+" & Buttons Edit & Del Added]
[image: Figure 3 - Clicked "+" & Buttons Edit & Del Added]